# How to kill some processes

Tags: rhel

I have some processes running on my linux machine, think that process ids are pid1 to pid100. Now I want to kill some processes like from pid25 to pid75 at a time. What is the way to perform this?

Comment: What is this range? You mean you have between 1 and 100 processes or are you referring to process ID numbers (PIDs)? Do you want to kill processes 25 through 75 or do you want to kill 25 processes at once? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: While you are editing, please make sure the title accurately summarizes the question you are asking. "Linux question 1" is a very unhelpful title or summary.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly doubt that you want to kill that many processes with pids in that range.

(Almost) per definition pid 1 is init, you don't want to kill that.

In most cases the next many pids are kernel threads, you don't want to kill those either. On my box the first pid assigned to an "ordinary" process is 310 - and I used quotes, because that's a part of systemd - unless you know what you're doing you don't want to kill that either.

If your box has been running for long enough (how long that is depends on how many processes you start) that pid allocation has wrapped around, you might have processes with low pids that it makes sense to kill (so much as it can ever).

Wanting to kill that many processes is another sign that you don't know what you're doing.

You really should tell us something about the processes you say you want to kill.

Comment: I dont mean pid 1 to pid 100 exactly, i am just taking some number for process ids